# Mac custom window maximization?

Tags: macos, window

I use macOS 12.0.1 (21A559). I need the following functionality:

Currently, when double-clicking the title bar of a window, the window is MAXIMIZED to the size of the whole screen.

Is there a built-in tool in macOS that automatically maximizes the window to a predefined custom size (and position) when double-clicking on the title bar instead of maximizing the window's size to the screen's size?

Comment: There's a rudimentary Split function - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948 You'd need 3rd party support for anything more.

Comment: 1. The Split Window dropdown menu appears on a Finder window, but not on a window of the app where I would need it (Vivaldi browser). 2. The Split window to the right/left side of the screen is useless for me, as I need a CUSTOM size.

Comment: Then you'll need a 3rd party app. Recommendations are off-topic here & belong on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ I can't recommend anything as I just put my windows where I want them, & there they stay, even through reboot.

Comment: Is it possible to customize the dimensions of the **Mac Desktop** area?

Comment: Have you done any research yourself, or are we just playing at "20 questions" trying to use me as your personal research assistant?